# Does a global object offer better performance than several local instances?

Tags: c++, oop, optimization, global

I'm currently refactoring some c++ for a genetic programming system. In the current code, I have an random number generator object available globally. Its setup like this

```
RNG.h
RNG.cpp   -> Instance created here

Globals.h -> includes 'RNG.h'
          -> extern RNG rng;

OtherClasses -> include 'Globals.h'
```

The RNG instance sets up a vector of generators, one for each available thread. I've spent time making this fast. This Global setup was convenient, but is this likely to be faster with an instance per translation unit? Is there a best practice around this sort of requirement?

Its often said to remove globals where possible, but it seems to fit well here.

Comment: `but is this likely to be faster with an instance per translation unit?` AFAIK you cant define one variable twice; the linker will surely yell at you

Comment: Ah - Yeah I mean creating the RNG as a member in the classes which use it.

Comment: there isn't a performance difference between globals and locals (unless a particular register allocation is performed) since the code is always in the code section.. but global variables are a terrible practice since they render the code thread-unsafe, prone to errors and unmaintainable

Comment: Is it not important that this would lead to different behavior? Sure, they're random numbers, but it's still different behavior.

Comment: It seems odd that the `RNG` has a generator per thread. How does it know how many threads there are? What happens if that number changes? One RNG per thread seems a much better mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean creating the RNG as a member in the classes which use it

This will likely reduce performance, as the RNG object is instantiated and initialized every time you create an object of a class containing it (opposed to a single initialization at program start).

You can however share your objects, e.g by using a `std::shared_ptr` or a raw pointer. You just have to pass them in the constructor to your objects then. If no RNG has been provided you could create one (overload the constructor). Especially by taking into consideration that RNGs are often seeded, this is probably the best solution.

Additionally you could implement a static `GetDefault()` method inside your RNG class (similiar to the singleton pattern, but without the restriction of one object per process).

Both things combined could result in an implementation like this:

```
class RNGUser
{
    std::shared_ptr<RNG> m_rng;

    RNGUser()
    : m_rng(RNG::GetDefault())
    {
    }

    RNGUser(std::shared_ptr<RNG> rng)
    : m_rng(rng)
    {
    }

};
```

Comment: Yes - point taken. I think I would have created it once and passed by reference into the objects which need it. I guess this still means that every object which needs to know about it would require it in the constructor. This might add a (negligible) performance hit as I've managed to keep to default constructors in many places. Being a GP system I'm generating objects very fast

Comment: I've just seen your edit. A static access method might be good

Comment: Well the solution I propose is a balancing act between performance and design (as this is propably not perfectly in sense of encapsulation), however if the RNG is an important part of your class, exposing it might be even better as it allows for more flexibility